# Generate Signed APK - Error:java: invalid source release: 14

Tags: android, flutter, signed-apk

Recently I started with Flutter and made an app, now I am trying to sign the APK for the release version as documented in: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

I have searched a lot on the internet but I have absolutely no clue what I am doing wrong..

When I try to generate the signed APK with my Keystore I am running into an error:

- Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'vista_presentie'
- Information:javac 1.8.0_242-release was used to compile java sources
- Information:Module "vista_presentie" was fully rebuilt due to project configuration/dependencies changes
- Information:28-10-2020 19:42 - Build completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 5 s 852 ms

** Error:java: invalid source release: 14

If I need to give some more information from the code I will update this question as soon as possible, please just ask me :)

Kind Regards,

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're using Java 1.8 to compile but in your android studio project you may have set the java language level to 14.

In Android Studio, go to Project Structure -> Modules -> Properties and
set **Source Compatibility** and **Target Compatibility** to `1.8 (Java 8)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry but I'm pretty new with Android Studio and can't find the properties in the module. I've added a screenshot of the module dialog.
http://kevinstevelmans.com/module_dialog_android_studio.png
Hope this is the right module dialog you described :)

Comment: You can see on your screenshot that the language level is "Project Default (14)", change it to 8, it should compile

Comment: Hmm okay, that fixed the java invalid source relase error, but now I got some other errors. Made also a screenshot of the errors and the file where the erros are comming from.
Errors: https://www.kevinstevelmans.com/android-studio/errors_android_studio.png

AndroidManifest.xml file: https://www.kevinstevelmans.com/android-studio/androidManifest.xml_android_studio.png

Comment: This is a different issue, your project is missing few resources as described in the errors you're getting. For example ic_launcher describes your app icon.
Have a look at the official documentation for more info https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources